# how to increment or decrement from variable until get char

Tags: c++

i wanted to create a snake program in console application.
but in one where i confused.
my problem like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int a=2000;
    while (1) {
        cout << time(0)<<endl;
        a -= 100;
        _sleep(a);
      **if (getch())break;
        else continue;
    }
}
```

my problem in **, i want from it ,to do that while loop until i pressed one key.
for example i want from it run like this:
print time().
a = 1900.
 wait 1.9s.
print time().
a=1800.
wait 1.8 s.
// now i pressed a key.
break.//end program

**so i found answer i used kbhit() in conio.h library.**

Comment: You will need to use platform specific API to determine when a key was pressed or released.  The standard C++ language has no facilities for key presses.  The C++ input functions *block* or wait at least until a character has arrived; some may wait for many characters are typed before acting upon them (such as pressing the Enter key).

Comment: Also, search the internet for "StackOverflow C++ snake game console" to see a plethora of similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this. Of course you need to do something in the parent process to have getchar() return for any key press without waiting, such as using _getchar().

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <signal.h>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    pid_t id;
    id = fork();
    if(id)
    {
      getchar();
      kill(id, SIGTERM);
    }
    else
    {
        int a=2000;
        while (1) {
            cout << time(0)<<endl;
            a -= 100;
            _sleep(a);
          /*if (getch())break;
            else continue;
            */
        }
    }
}
```